# How to chain commands for pandas.read_sql_query?

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy and Pandas. I have a "SET" SQL statement, followed by a "SELECT".

At the moment, I'm doing:

```
query1 = "SET..."
result = sql_engine.execute(query1)
query2 = "SELECT..."
df = pd.read_sql_query(query2, sql_engine)
```

But sometimes the query returns empty. Is there a way that I can chain both queries so that it happens in one go? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by issuing a single SQL statement, rather than breaking it up into two.